# Docker: how do i format a CMD/EntryPoint to run my client and server in the same terminal

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Concurrently allows me to run client and server simultaneously within the same terminal and the command for it is `npm run dev` from my server folder.

I am trying to avoid creating multiple Dockerfiles for client and server folder.

After building and image of my whole project, is it possible to use `docker run [image]` to call on `CMD or ENTRYPOINT [npm run dev]` to replicate the same behaviour as starting my application outside of docker? How would i format my DockerFile to go into server folder and run`npm run dev` to load up client and server?

i gave my code a try and apparently the error i get back is `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "npm run dev": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the [exec form of ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)/[CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> Command line arguments to docker run  will be appended after
> all elements in an exec form ENTRYPOINT, and will override all
> elements specified using CMD. This allows arguments to be passed to
> the entry point, i.e., docker run  -d will pass the -d argument
> to the entry point. You can override the ENTRYPOINT instruction using
> the docker run --entrypoint flag.
>
> The shell form prevents any CMD or run command line arguments from
> being used, but has the disadvantage that your ENTRYPOINT will be
> started as a subcommand of /bin/sh -c, which does not pass signals.
> This means that the executable will not be the container’s PID 1 - and
> will not receive Unix signals - so your executable will not receive a
> SIGTERM from docker stop .

To run `num run dev` on our container, you should use either

```
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "dev"] # using the exec form correctly
```

or

```
ENTRYPOINT npm run dev # using the shell form
```